# 'transcirbe_steaming_infinite.py' mics setup(multiple channels) can have an effect on response's arriving time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyaudio, google-cloud-speech, portaudio, watson-assistant

I have tried to use [transcirbe_steaming_infinite.py] module with multiple mics. The first one is equipped on my pc(mac book pro) and the other one is external one (Jabra EVOLVE 20). Through Audio MIDI setup I made an aggregate device option (Jabra for channel #1, mac for #2).

To use these mics I modified the codes like ResumableMicrophoneStream._num_channels as 2 and added two extra lines after RecognitionConfig audio_channel_count=2 and enable_seperate_recognition_per_channel=True. And the language in ja-JP

When I tried to use these codes at least work (they are able to recognize each channels) but the problem is that in a certain case, responses comes too late.

The case is when I switch the mic from one of each to the other one. For example, when I try to  use mic on channel #1(Jabra) right after using the mic on channel #2, I cannot get the response in time but about 15000ms later.

When I checked the mics on Audio MIDI setup those two's sample rate was different(16kHz, 44.1kHz per each), so I thought up with a possibility it has affected on the library processing audio input streams like PyAudio and finally it has caused late request and response as well. It will be dummiest hypothesis XD.

So I want to know, as the title this problem(late response) can be fixed with good mics setup or just there is another good problem solving way for this case.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of latency is the API not detecting the end of the audio and therefore it will continue to listen and process audio until either the stream is closed directly, or the stream's limit length has been exceeded. You can discard it using [single_utterance](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.StreamingRecognitionConfig.html#Google_Cloud_Speech_V1_StreamingRecognitionConfig_SingleUtterance) which indicates whether the request should automatically end after speech is no longer detected. Also if you are using noise filtering, that should be removed so that Cloud sees the raw audio and can properly detect isFinal.

If the latency issues only occurs when mics are changed and you are following the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices), you can reach the STT team through the [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)